# Letter frequency for loop in Python

Tags: python

Hey can anyone help me here
I'm supposed to get a number count for each letter used in this string here using for loops and if statement.

quote= "I watched in awe as I saw her swim across the ocean"

The pseudocode given is this:

```
for every letter in the alphabet list:
    Create a variable to store the frequency of each letter in the string and assign it an initial value of zero
    for every letter in the given string:
        if the letter in the string is the same as the letter in the alphabet list
            increase the value of the frequency variable by one.
    if the value of the frequency variable does not equal zero:
        print the letter in the alphabet list followed by a colon and the value of the frequency variable
```

This is what i've got so far but i cannot for the life of me figure it out.

```
quote =  "I watched in awe as I saw her swim across the ocean."

xquote= quote.lower()
print(xquote)

alphabet= ["a", "b", "c", "d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
for i in alphabet:
  c_alphabet= {"a": 0, "b":0, "c":0, "d":0,"e":0,"f":0,"g":0,"h":0,"i":0,"j":0,"k":0,"l":0,"m":0,"n":0,"o":0,"p":0,"q":0,"r":0,"s":0,"t":0,"u":0,"v":0,"w":0,"x":0,"y":0,"z":0}
  for i in xquote:
    if i == alphabet:
      c_alphabet[i]+=1
print(c_alphabet)
```

I don't get an error message but I just can't seem to be able to get a total number of individual letters  in the string.

I'd like it to output some thing like this c_alphabet = {"a": 3, "b":1, "c": 2...)

Answer (score 0):

There are more eloquent ways to do this, but using your algorithm, the problem is that you're mixing up variables. You're comparing `i` to `alphabet`, shadowing the variable `i`, and redefining `c_alphabet` in every top-level loop. See the changes here:

```
quote = "I watched in awe as I saw her swim across the ocean."
xquote = quote.lower()

alphabet = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" ]

# moved out of loop
c_alphabet = { "a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0, "h": 0, "i": 0, "j": 0, "k": 0, "l": 0, "m": 0, "n": 0, "o": 0, "p": 0, "q": 0, "r": 0, "s": 0, "t": 0, "u": 0, "v": 0, "w": 0, "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0 }

for i in alphabet:
    for j in xquote: # changed variable name
        if i == j:   # changed comparison
            c_alphabet[i] += 1

print(c_alphabet)
```

A much more concise version would be:

```
# lowercase, filter to only alphanumeric characters, and then sort that
formatted = sorted(filter(str.isalnum, quote.lower()))
# build the dict
count_dict = {a: formatted.count(a) for a in formatted}
print(count_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Been banging my head to try solving this problem. If I may ask, what do you mean by shadowing the variable I?

Comment: @LuckyB Variable shadowing means having same-named variables in an inner scope as in an outer scope. In this case you had `for i...` inside of another loop using `i` as the iterator, so the outer one would've been ignored by your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The `strings` library has the lowercase alphabet is you're allowed to use it.  I believe this is true to the pseudo code, with the exception that the keys of the `count` dictionary are used instead of a list.  This example also prints the non-zero letter frequencies as required.

```
import string
quote =  "I watched in awe as I saw her swim across the ocean."
count = {letter:0 for letter in string.ascii_lowercase}
for letter in quote.lower():
    if letter in count:
        count[letter]+=1

print(*(f'{letter}: {freq}' for letter, freq in count.items() if freq != 0), sep=", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is usually the simplest one

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(quote.lower())
```

Comment: Definitely the most elegant solution, but it doesn't match the pseudocode given as the problem.

Comment: That is true Indeed